# AMPScript to normalize Mobile Phone fieldswithin in data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, dataextensions, cloudpage

Our contacts are synchronized through the Marketing Cloud Connector. The MobilePhone field is formatted with 10 digits in Sales Cloud and values do not begin with a 1. In order to send SMS through journey builder the phone field requires phone numbers to begin with a 1 (for US) or otherwise be 11 digits. Thus, we are unable to send to the vast majority of our contacts because they have a 10 digit phone number without a 1 at the beginning.

I wrote AMPScript in a CloudPage that should update the MobilePhone field within a targeted Data Extension, but I have been unable to fire the AMPScript after loading the page.

The AMPScript I wrote is below.

Note the 'Processed' field is a boolean field with a default value as false; it should change to "True" once the number has been normalized. All contacts in the Data Extension are SMS_Opt_in__c = True. Also, the Data Extension is populated via SQL activity - I don't know if that matters. The Data extension contains about 65k contacts. (Please forgive formatting issues as this is my first GitHub post).

```
%%[ 
    set @de = "Kit Shipped SMS"
    set @newNumberRows = LookupRows(@de, "Processed", "False", "SMS_Opt_in__c", "True")
    set @rowCount = rowCount(@newNumberRows)

    for @r = 1 to @rowCount do
      set @current_row = row(@newNumberRows, @r)
          set @badPhone = field(@current_row, "MobilePhone")
          set @rowID = field(@current_row, "ContactKey")
    ]%%

%%[for @i = 1 to length(@badPhone) do
  set @char = substring(@badPhone,@i,1)
  set @result = iif(empty(regexmatch(@char,'\d+',0)),concat(@result,''),concat(@result,@char))
  next @i

]%%

    %%[
    if length(@result) == "10" then
       set @finalNumber = concat("1", @result)
         UpsertData(@de, 1,"ContactKey", @rowID, "MobilePhone", @finalNumber, "Processed", "True")
    elseif length(@result) == '11' then
       set @finalNumber = @result
       UpsertData(@de, 1,"ContactKey", @rowID, "MobilePhone", @finalNumber, "Processed", "True")
    else
       set @finalNumber = @result
       UpsertData(@de, 1,"ContactKey", @rowID, "Processed", "True")
    endif
    ]%%
    %%[
    set @result =""
    set @finalNumber = ""
    next @r
    ]%%


    ]%%


    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title></title>
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
 <br>Row Count: %%=v(@rowCount)=%%
 <br>Data Extension: %%=v(@de)=%%

</body>
</html>
```

When loading this CloudPage, I see this:

Row Count: 0
Data Extension: Kit Shipped SMS

Is there something wrong with this code or is there a better way to perform this action?

Comment: I would not try doing this with ampscript as the solution will be inefficient and difficult to scale. My advice to you is to stop looking for a workaround and tell the SF admins/devs to tighten up their data entry requirements or create a field that auto-appends the digit, and cleans up any formatting issues, on that end. If that's not possible, then your best bet is to use data extension entry events where you can normalize the phone input before journey entry but I'd highly advise you fix this at the source rather than cleaning it up.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. Being aware this is far from a scalable solution, I have brought this up to our SF admins, but the request has to go through the formal intake process and added to the backlog (where things go to die). 

How does one normalize the phone input before the journey entry? That is basically what I am trying to accomplish by modifying the values within the entry Data Extension via AMPScript. Thanks again.

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to implement this? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318131&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Also if you are segmenting the entry source, why don't you handle this with a SQL query

Comment: Thanks, @EazyE. I didn't realize it was possible to normalize the phone number fields in the query. I know basic SQL so I assume this approach will be a learning opportunity for me. Do you have any tips or perhaps an example of how to write a SQL query that normalizes phone numbers?

Comment: select concat('1',mobilefieldname) as mobilefieldname from salesforce_contact

Comment: you can also use a case statement for different lengths. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp. Select case when len(mobilefieldname) = 11 then mobilefieldname else concat('1',mobilefieldname) END as mobilefieldname

Comment: Thank you @EazyE. I just added concat('1',mobilephone) as mobilephone into the existing query and it appeared to work!